# Sprite Kit / Objective C : What is the "touch indicator" for objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, sprite-kit, sprite

I am referring to the menu screen of my `SpriteKit` game. I used image `SpriteNodes` for the start and options button.

I want to change to the "game view" if I touch the start button, and "options view" if the options button's pressed.

Should be an easy question, but I couldn't find any resources for this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to indicate to the user that something has been touched (i.e. some sort of highlight or audible feedback?) or are you asking what event the operating system will trigger when something is touched? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `SpriteKit` for detect which `SKSpriteNode` is touched there is property `.name`

```
 SKSpriteNode *toGame = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"game"];
 toGame.name = @"toGame";
 ...

 SKSpriteNode *toOptions = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"options"];
 toOptions.name = @"toOptions";
 ...
```

after in `touchesBegan`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

 SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

 if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"toGame"]) {

    //go to game scene
 }

 if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"toOptions"]) {

    // go to options scene    
 }
```