# How do I get to know what sprite has been touched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have some sprites coming from the bottom of the screen in a random order. I want to swipe the sprite in the direction of the swipe. I got the algorithm for swiping. Also, I get an NSLog message whenever any sprite has been touched in the screen. The NSLog gives correct responses to any and every object touched. But how do I know which sprite has been swiped to write the code for applying impulse to that particular sprite?

I am trying the following code:

```
               SKNode *sprite = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
               [ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx, dy) atPoint:location];
               [self addChild:sprite];
```

Also,

userInteractionEnabled = YES for all the sprites

And all the sprites are performing an action (Just in case this is the reason why I cannot swipe them while they are already running an action, in this case what else should I use to move the sprites?)

Sorry if this is too dumb, I am a noob

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprite Kit / Objective C : What is the "touch indicator" for objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132020/sprite-kit-objective-c-what-is-the-touch-indicator-for-objects)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the name of the sprite with the name property:

```
node.name = @"nodeName";



for(SKNode *node in [self nodesAtPoint:location])
{
    if([node.name isEqualToString:@"nodeName"])
        {
            // your custom code here
        }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, if not i am always here to help.

Comment: Okay, so I tried that. But I dunno if it is reaching there. I added the following code to addImpulse to the sprite that has be swiped:

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sprite"]) {
                        [sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx, dy) atPoint:location];
                    
                    }

Comment: wouldn't I have to add node if I used node.physicsBody? 
and still no impulse is being applied :(